# Is there a way to use Input selection on Joptionpane

Tags: java

I am a first-year computer science student. Coding in java is pretty new to me but I have achieved solutions to some of my problems. I have a question I'm struggling with, it asks me to use `JOptionPane` as a selection method. I know how to use the default selection dialog box but my question requires me to use `JOptionPane` to show choices(eg 1, withdraw 2, deposit 3, print details), and then it requires me to press 1, 2 or 3 to run that instruction. I have failed to find a way to input choice please may I be assisted :)`

```
public String setTown(){

    weightSelection w1 = new weightSelection();

    String [] towns = {"Durban","Pretoria","Cape Town"};

     String input = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please select townoption",
    "The Choice of a Lifetime", JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, // Use
                                                                    // default
                                                                    // icon
    towns, // Array of choices
    towns[1]); // Initial choice
    choice = input;
    System.out.println(choice);
    w1.setWeight();`
```

Comment: Did you try using the version that lets you select values? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInternalInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: I did not try it, ill try using showinternalInputdialog

Comment: I linked the internal one, but there is also a non-internal version: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog(java.awt.Component,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String,%20int,%20javax.swing.Icon,%20java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.Object)

Comment: I have made a break through to the choice selection, there is an addition to the question that says after the selection is made it should call for another method. I just wish i could show question so you know whats happening

Comment: You can add images of the gui. Also, you can edit your question to add the code your using now.

Comment: I have linked the question you can take a look

Comment: I'm sorry, there was some confusion. I meant an image from your gui. Add the code your using now, where you create a choice selection dialog, and then we can figure out how you call the next bit of code after you get the choice selection.

Comment: Oh i see i took picture of my code now

Comment: Oh no, do not use pictures of your code. Put the actual code in the question, but when you run the code and you have a gui showing, you can paste pictures of that.

Comment: Sorry for being dumb im new to this community :( I hope what ive done now is what you are saying

Comment: This is getting much better. You're fleshing out an actual question that can be answered with some code. Asking a question on SO can be a challenge. What is wrong with your code now? You run the code, do you see the dialog? Does choice show the value you need?

Comment: Yes it is running perfectly fine i saw some code posted down below and have managed to get a breakthrough

Answer (score 0):

If you write

```
 String [] towns = {"1. Durban","2. Pretoria","3. Cape Town"};
```

and the dialog opens the User might only need to press 1 or 2 or 3 on the keyboard.

Because the optionpane has the `focus` it recieves the keyhits and have a natural behaivor in selecting matching options to that keyhit.

Unfortunately the user have to hit "return" or click "ok" to confirm the selection and close the dialog.

Comment: I understand let me add that and see what turns up. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Here is another example you could try

```
String dialogmessage = "Please choose a dessert"; 
String[] desserts = {"Cheesecake","Ice Cream","Mousse","Carrot cake"}
String dessert = (String)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(dialogcombo.this, dialogmessage, dialogtitle, JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null, dessert, dessert[0]);
if(dessert == null){
showStatus("You clicked cancel");}
else{showStatis("Your Choice was: " + dessert);}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you very much i have added some concepts of your code into to mine it seems to be working fine so far

Comment: Your welcome. I guess that you are also new to this site? Could you please rate the answer given using the up/down arrows to the left of the answer. Positive integer good (1) negative integer (-1) not good. If you have any further question or queries then please post them.

Answer (score 0):

Code is running smoothly and has no errors, though my output for t1.choice is null
he is the code

```
    System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Your Recipt" + "\n"+ "**********************" + "\n" + "Town: "+ "  " + t1.choice  );
```